# Laravel migraciones Datetime

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, migration

Estoy realizando un insert a mi tabla usuario, quiero que me inserte en un campo la fecha y en otro la hora, pero tengo la función "timestamp" la cual pone por defecto ambas en el mismo campo, ¿ como podría estructurar para que las tome en campos diferentes ?
La fecha y hora las quiero tomar del sistema

> Esta es mi migración

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('usuario', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('chat_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('tries')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp();

    });

}
```

Eh intentado utilizando la clase Carbon de laravel pero no me funciona en mi insert

Esta es la sugerencia que me hicieron, pero no me funciona:

```
<?php
```

namespace App;

use BotMan\BotMan\Interfaces\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon\Carbon;

```
class Usuarios extends Model
{

protected $fillable = ['chat_id', 'name', 'tries',,'mi_fecha','mi_hora'];
protected $table = 'usuario';

protected $casts = [
'mi_fecha' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
'mi_hora' => 'datetime:H:i:s'
];

// $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();

public static function saveUser(UserInterface $botUser)
{
    $user = static::updateOrCreate(['chat_id' => $botUser->getId()], [
        'chat_id' => $botUser->getId(),
        'name' => $botUser->getFirstName().' '.$botUser->getLastName(),
        'mi_fecha' => $miFecha = now()->toDateString();
        'mi_hora' => $miHora = now()->toTimeString();
    ]);
    $user->increment('tries');
    $user->save();
    return $user;
}



}
```

?>

Comment: a que te refieres con *en un campo la fecha y en otro el día*? es decir en una columna solo quieres mes y año y en otro el día?

Comment: perdona, fecha y hora en diferentes campos

Comment: En tú esquema estas declarando una variable timestamp pero no le haz indicado el nombre. ¿La fecha y hora que quieres inserta es la del momento del registro o es desde el formulario?

Comment: Que la tome del sistema, al momento del registro

Comment: ¿por qué o para qué defines $miFecha al momento de guardar el timestamp? ¿ya agregaste los dos campos a la migración?

Comment: Ya funciono, muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define entonces dos campos en la migración, uno para la fecha y otro para la hora:

```
$table->date('mi_fecha');
$table->time('mi_hora');
```

Recuerda (en caso de ser necesario) definirlos como fechas en el modelo, y utilizar la propiedad casts para el formato deseado:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'mi_fecha', 'mi_hora'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'mi_fecha' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'mi_hora' => 'datetime:H:i:s'
];
```

Al momento de almacenarlos, obtienes la parte que necesitas, directamente de la instancia de Carbon:

```
$miFecha = now()->toDateString();
$miHora = now()->toTimeString();
```

O con el método format();

Comment: Ya lo intente de esa forma pero en  mi insert me marca error, actualizo en la pregunta para que veas como lo tengo, gracias :)

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: No me muestra errores, uso botman studio con la api de telegram, desarrollo un chatbot, se que hay error porque se cicla la respuesta y no hay registros en mi base de datos, es al momento de pasarlo a mi funcion para insertar